# Predicting output size of compressed video (MoviePy)

Tags: python, video, statistics, compression, regression

I am about to make the following experiment, but wondering if the chosen approach is correct hence the cry for help. To goal is to be able to develop a general rough rule of thumb for the target video clip size. We have an input video and, using MoviePy library, want to have an output video that should not exceed a certain arbitrary output size. The output is created by accelerating the input video:

```
VideoFileClip(fname).without_audio().fx(vfx.resize, 0.3).fx(vfx.speedx, 4)
```

So, if we set a target that the output should not exceed 200kb, the question is what speed rate should be applied for a video of size 3mb, 10mb, 20mb?

To do that the idea was to take a sample of random videos, try out different speed rates, and find a line best fit on the outputs. What is your take on that approach? I know that it's a very coarse measure rendering different results depending on the input type, but still...Thanks